# Explicit expression for the Poisson kernel solving the Dirichlet problem for geodesic balls

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, laplacian, integral-kernel

> Let $X$ be a Riemannian manifold with the Laplace-Beltrami operator denoted by $\mathscr L$ and we look at its geodesic balls say $B$. Let $u$ be a continuous function on the geodesic sphere which is the boundary of $B$ , denote it by $\partial B$. Then what is the explicit expression for the Poisson kernel that solves the Dirichlet problem:  \begin{cases} 
>       \mathscr{L}f= 0 & B \\
>       f=u & \partial B \\
>          \end{cases}

Apart from the usual Euclidean setting, I have only been able to find some expressions for the Real hyperbolic space, the Sphere etc in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/41387389_The_Poisson_Integral_for_a_Ball_in_Spaces_of_Constant_Curvature). What can we say about more general spaces, are there some well-known results?

**Please note that I am looking for an explicit expression for the Poisson kernel, not merely the solvability of the Dirichlet problem.**